# Visual Studio Platform 2015 Toolset ='v141' cannot be found Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to compile a class lib in Visual Studio 2019 and i am getting this back as an Error. Why is this so? and I have not seen a way to install in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise

Comment: VS 2015 should toolset should be v140. v141 = 2017 https://marcofoco.com/microsoft-visual-c-version-map/

Comment: Launch Visual Studio Installer, select "Modify" for your VS 2019 installation, go to "Individual components", and select the VS 2015 toolchain.

Comment: alternatively, you can change toolset to one that exists in your installation, from project settings

Comment: @IInspectable, nothing like that here

Comment: @zapredelom, still wont compile. Only compiles for 32 bit

Comment: You never mentioned, that it *did* compile for a 32-bit target. What build system (or build system generator) does this library use? CMake? MSBuild? Something else?

Comment: BTW, You really need to provide some way (more information about what you are doing and how you are doing this) for us to help you on this question. As it is currently worded I highly doubt that anyone could solve this. @IInspectable raises some very good points.

Comment: Why don't you try to select VS 2017 toolset v141?